# Issue with visibility key frames affecting multiple objects

Tags: animation

I'm encountering an issue when I press <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering my mouse over the [`Disable in Renders`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/outliner.html#collections) [image] icon  for one object which affects one or more objects causing them to go invisible as well when trying to animate. I have tried reloading a different project, recreating the object, as well as unlinking it from any object possible.

I'm still new to Blender so I can guarantee that I may have missed something. Got any ideas about what is going on?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I have edited the post for my blender file. You will be able to take a look at it there.